# About a special case of continuity in cartesian product of compacts result

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, compactness

I want to prove the following statement:

Given $f: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, let $\phi:[0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be  defined as $\phi(r) =sup_{|x| = r} f(x)$. Show that $\phi$ is continuous.

I was able to prove this result: "If $K$, $L$ are compact metric spaces and $f:K\times L \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, for each $y \in L$, put $\phi(y) = sup_{x\in K}f(x,y)$. Prove that $\phi:L\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as defined is continuous."

Can I generalize for $K_{1} \times K_{2} \times ...\times K_{n}$ and make it a special case of it (as in putting $\phi(r)$ as $\phi(x_{1},...,x_{n}) = supf(x_{1},..., x_{n})$)? (**main question**)
If you have any other (simple) ideas, please enlighten me.

Comment: $K_1 \times K_2 \times \dotsc \times K_n \cong (K_1 \times \dotsc \times K_{n-1}) \times K_n$. Also, look at $S^{n-1}\times [0,+\infty)$. That $[0,+\infty)$ isn't compact, and that $S^{n-1}\times [0,+\infty)$ isn't homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ doesn't really matter.

Comment: That's true. Any ideas on how to approach it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the topological product is associative (up to homeomorphism), the generalisation of your result to products with more than two factors is immediate once you know that the product of compact spaces is again compact (that even holds for products of infinitely many spaces).

But you look at the supremum (maximum) of $f$ on the sphere or radius $r$, and thus it doesn't help to look at $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}\times \dotsc \times \mathbb{R}$. You want to use a product where one of the factors is a sphere. Thus let $S^{n-1} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lvert x\rvert = 1\}$ (whatever norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ you use, the result is topologically the same), and look at the map

$$\mu \colon S^{n-1} \times [0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^n,\quad (r,\xi) \mapsto r\cdot \xi.$$

Then $\mu$ is a continuous surjection (and the restriction to $S^{n-1} \times (0,+\infty)$ is a homeomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$), and you can apply the result you proved to the map $\tilde{f} := f\circ \mu$ when you restrict to compact subsets of $[0,+\infty)$. Since continuity is a local property, you immediately obtain the continuity of $\phi$ from your result by noting that

$$\phi(r) = \sup \{ \tilde{f}(r,\xi) : \xi \in S^{n-1}\}.$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be S^(n-1) be with x belonging to R^(n-1)?

Comment: No, the dimension of the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $n-1$. But however we denote it, we want $r\cdot \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$, so we must have $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: And I can use that the cartesian product of homeomorphisms is a homeomorphism, right? If I had to prove that your restriction is a homeomorphism to R^n\{0}, I would only have to prove the product of the circle by the real line is homeomorphic to the plane without the origin. Nice take on restricting to compact subsets of the domain and using continuity is only a local property! Thank you!